# How to render/show webpage in OpenGL Context?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, html

I'm crating a simple launcher for my game.
My launcher is cross-platform GUI application. I'm using C++, SDL2 and OpenGL to create really nice GUI application with some buttons, images, text, etc...

But now I want to make news page somewhere in my launcher. When I was creating my very first launcher (Windows only and C# instead of C++) there was a form builder in Visual C#, but now I'm creating GUI application using C++, without any builders, just SDL2, OpenGL. Visual C# has ready panel for web context inside his toolbox.

But now my question is how can I render/show webpage using OpenGL?
I want to achieve something like a webpanel from Visual C#'s toolbox.
It's called WebBrowser or something...

Maybe there is a way to render page inside SDL surface or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering a WebPage is a full time job for a team of developers (I'm thinking about Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge/IE, ... guys).

About the C# [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) windows form component:

> The WebBrowser control is a managed wrapper around a component
>   installed with Internet Explorer.

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Actually, as it is say [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15433/sdl-or-opengl-html5-gecko-and-vector-movies):

> One solution (probably the easiest at the moment but not necessary the
>   best) is to include a complete web browser engine into your game.
>
> ```
> Awesomium seems to be the more popular.
> Berkelium is an alternative solution, that I didn't tried yet.
> ```